# Jackson (de)serialization not accurate between HTTP responses and test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-schema-validator, jackson2

I have a Spring Boot `2.3.2.RELEASE` WebFlux application. I have some JPA entities that are returned as part of the RESTful API responses.

The tests that I have (using `@WebFluxTest`) check the HTTP response(s) and contract — against a JSON schema. I'm injecting a Jackson's `ObjecMapper` and a Spring `WebTestClient` in those tests to check the HTTP response(s) against the corresponding/expected JSON schema.

The problem is: if I use any HTTP client when the application is running, the collections (on the Java side) with no elements are serialized into JSON as empty arrays — that's what I would expect regardless of whether that's right or wrong theoretically; but on the test cases, the same empty collections are being serialized with `null` values.

So I wonder **why would that be different**? I would expect the same JSON string at any point.

I know I'm not using different `ObjectMapper` settings — or that's what I think. I don't have any custom Spring beans for that type, so I'm using whatever Spring Boot injects by default, so it must be the same for the running application as well as when running the tests. The only customization for Jackson is done at the application level in the `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  ...
  jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
    serialization:
      write-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds: false
      write-dates-as-timestamps: true
  ...
```

> I'm using the `com.networknt:json-schema-validator:1.0.43` library for the JSON schema implementation.

---

Excerpt of one of the test cases:

```kotlin
@WebFluxTest(controllers = [ExamController::class])
internal class ExamControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var webClient: WebTestClient

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

  @Test
  @Disabled
  fun getById_ValidateResponseAgainstSchema() {
    // IMPORTANT: If you update anything here, make the corresponding changes also to getById_WhenRecordExists
    webClient.get()
        .uri("/exams/10001030")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk
        .expectBody()
        .consumeWith { result ->
          val schemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V201909)
          this::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/json-schemas/exam/exam-details.json").use {
            Assertions.assertThat(schemaFactory.getSchema(it).validate(mapper.readTree(result.responseBody))).isEmpty()
          }
        }
  }

  // ...
}
```

The test data is created/seeded in a Docker container using Testcontainers.

Comment: Could you include the relevant code? I would suspect, that if you read the entities using Spring data, any one-to-many association would be initialized with an empty collection. If on the other hand you just new up the entities in your test code, the collections will probably be null unless you initialize the collections correctly yourself. But it‘s hard to tell without knowing what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I'm using an end-to-end workflow for these ones. Let me put an excerpt with the relevant parts of the failing test case.

Comment: Could you also include the serialization part in your production code and the deserialized JSON, that is sent over the wire? I suspect, that you're serializing a Java POJO? In your test case you're deserializing into a `JSonNode` instead of a POJO. So that might be a difference, but it doesn't explain your problem with the `null` values yet, because Jackson should deserialize an empty array into an array, unless you have `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT` enabled somewhere (and that's just for POJOs as far as I know)

Comment: And you were right; a co-worker configured it in such way just for the tests. I didn't realize about it, but that's exactly the setting: `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT`. Now the funny part was that it didn't fail on the change because the JSON schema was written wrongly, which is what I was fixing this time. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Great! Just posted that as an answer. Would be happy, if you could accept the answer and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT`, so that Jackson doesn‘t deserialize empty arrays as null values